# Facing System.Text.Encoding.Web Error while trying to fetch all users with Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, .net-3.0

I have been exploring with Azure and Graph API. I have created two apps, one is a MVC app and other one is a Azure Function app. When I try `graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync()`, I am getting data in MVC App but I am facing error like System.Text.Encoding.Web version=6.0.0.0 with Azure Function. However, in the function app too, I am getting data if I try for a specific user like `graphClient.Users[Id].Requests().GetAsync()`. Here's my code snippet for initializing and making request.

```
clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId");
tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TenantId");
clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientSecret");

_clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();

graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {

    var authResult = await _clientApplication
        .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();

    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
    })

var result = await graphClient.Users.Request().Top(100).GetAsync();
```

My .NET Version is 3.1 and I am using latest Graph API i.e. 4.5.0 and Version of Microsoft.NET.sdk.Functions is 3.1.1. I tried using Filter so as to avoid any internals that might be resulting in my issue but this is of no use. I tried my testcase in other laptop with .net6 and it is working as expected. However, I need to run this with netcore3.1. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Please add more details about the error like exception, stack trace etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, I saw you both used Graph SDK and generating an access token. In my humble opinion, since this is an Azure function, you should add `User.Read.All` **application** API permission then using client credential flow. Could you pls try my code below?

I created a function with portal experience and code like below:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
    var clientId = "azure_ad_app_id";
    var clientSecret = "client_secret";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
    return new OkObjectResult("hello");
}
```

I created a file `function.proj` in kudo which add the reference. Here [the runtime must](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp?tabs=functionsv2#using-nuget-packages) be `netstandard2.0`.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">  
    <PropertyGroup>  
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>  
    <ItemGroup>  
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.51.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.8.1" />
    </ItemGroup>  
</Project>
```